# Responsive YouTube embed with text

Tags: html, css, responsive

To begin with - I'm CSS / HTML beginner so something that might be obvious for you - for me is just not :) Would really appreciate your help.

I'm having a problem regarding positioning of the text on responsive YouTube embed.

What I'm trying to accomplish is:

- responsive Youtube video that scales well for all resolutions - it works well
- text should be placed on top of the Youtube embed - right now it disappears in back
- text should be position in the same place in relation to video embed (for all the resolutions) - in my final example text should be placed on right, approx 25% up from the bottom end of the Youtube embed
- I want to have access to Youtube embed controls (e.g. pausing on click and so on) so any layer covering youtube embed won't be OK
- I would prefer a solution of html/css (without any additional js)

Source that I have is the following:

```css
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 0px;
  /* size of chrome */
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AqG147-XEWg?wmode=opaque&autoplay=1&loop=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>
      Example text
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

If some of you guys would be able to help with text positioning, I'd really appreciate

Comment: Can you explain the position of the text more clearly? It says it should be above the video embed in one place, then says it should be on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is super close. We just need to position the `.text` element absolutely and use some `right` and `bottom` properties to align it. In the example below I've used:

```
.text {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 25%;
}
```

I've also changed the `.text` color to `white` so it's visible, but this could be changed depending on the colors in the video.

```css
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 0px;
  /* size of chrome */
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  right: 5%;
  bottom: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AqG147-XEWg?wmode=opaque&autoplay=1&loop=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>
      Example text
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was trying to do!